# How can I delete the or3 and & notations from this and gate?

Tags: pstricks, pst-circ

```
\documentclass{exam}  
\usepackage{pst-circ}  
\usepackage{multicol}  
\begin{document}  
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(5,4)  
\logic[logicWidth=2,unit=0.5,logicHeight=4,logicNInput=3](-2,-2){or3}  
\end{pspicture}   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The version pf `pst-circ.tex` from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-circ/ knows the optional arguments `logicLabelstyle` and `logicSymbolstyle`. You can set these parameters to an empty argument:

```
\documentclass{exam}  
\usepackage{pst-circ}  
\begin{document}  

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(5,4)  
\logic[logicWidth=1,logicHeight=2,logicNInput=3,
  logicSymbolstyle=,logicLabelstyle=](-2,-2){or3}  
\end{pspicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]